# How to get interval between hours and put into list from start into finish?

Tags: c#

For example, I will be given a time on hours with type `DateTime` hours like this

#### for the starter

1. my starttime is 00:00
2. endtime is 02:00

and every time 30 minutes I like to input the value into a `List<DateTime>`
so, how can I get the value to put into a list that is look like this?

- 00:00
- 00:30
- 01:00
- 01:30
- 02:00

**My Code**

```
        DateTime starTime = new DateTime();
        DateTime endTimes = new DateTime();
        DateTime interval = new DateTime();
        List<DateTime> intervals = new List<DateTime>();
        starTime = DateTime.ParseExact(fulldate + "00:00",
                                "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        endTimes = DateTime.ParseExact(fulldate + "02:00",
                                "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); ;
        interval = starTime;
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            interval.AddHours(0.5);
            intervals.Add(interval);
            if (interval.ToString("HH:mm") == endTimes.ToString("HH:mm"))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Can you explain how your current implementation does not work as intended? And what should happen if the difference between `starTime` and `endTimes` is not divisible by 30 minutes?

Comment: it's seems that i didn't get any increment +30 minutes only just 1 times

Comment: @RickyRezaMuhammad the problem is that `AddHours` doesn't update the existing value, it **returns a new one** which you don't do anything with (you ignore the return value). You need to use the new value, ie: `interval = interval.AddHours(0.5)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some assumption (that end time is on the same day, that your end time is always something that can be devided by 30 mins, ...)  this would work.

```
var start = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
var end = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);
var current = start;

List<DateTime> values = new List<DateTime>();
var startDate = DateTime.Now.Date; // editited after @pinkflowydx33's comment 

values.Add(startDate + start);

while (current < end)
{
    current = current.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));
    values.Add(startDate + current);
}

foreach (var v in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v);
}
```

Comment: It would be better not to make any assumptions and just do - while until end is reached. Code-wise the example is already very close.

Comment: Maybe you change to `TimeSpan.FromHours` and `TimeSpan.FromMinutes` for better readability?

Comment: @gsharp thank you it's work, maybe the problem it's just the logic,

Comment: `startDate = DateTime.Today` or `startDate = DateTime.Now.Date` or `startDate = now.Date` all do the same thing but are *perhaps*  clearer

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 shoooooot all this years doing it with new DateTime(a,b,c) ... and always thinking than can't be it... there must be an easier way  ;-)) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i prepared that type of solution. - It's loop over number, which represent - times of valueToChange - in this specific case between 30 minutes - and add to the startDate - 30 minutes and also saving to list.

```
  using System;
                        
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            
            List<DateTime> intervals = new List<DateTime>();
            
            var changeValue = 30;
            
            var startDate = new DateTime(2010, 05, 12, 13, 00, 00);
            var endDate = new DateTime(2010, 05, 12, 14, 00, 00);
    
            var timeIntervals = System.Math.Abs(startDate.Subtract(endDate).TotalMinutes / changeValue);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < timeIntervals; i++)
            {
               startDate.AddMinutes(30);
               intervals.Add(startDate)
            }
    
    
        }
    }
```

---

In this case the start and end date are divided by 30 minutes without rest - so if there will be 13:00 and 13:12 - it's doesn't add the value to List - cause the value doesn't > 30.

Comment: it's work at least but the between value still leave me with the startdate. but from your answer i finally solved my problem

Comment: i'm using gsharp answer when it come to looping and just adding `AddMinutes(30)`, anyway thank you

Comment: This answer suffers the same as the OP. You need to **use the return value of `AddMinutes`**, it doesn't update the existing value

Comment: Why? It’s shouldn’t maybe? What are assumptions?